# Rails route hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to get someone else's app up and running on my development laptop but I ran into a routing issue and I'm not sure how to debug it. For a particular controller/action, it just hangs and doesn't time out and there is no error message in the development log. Does anyone know how I can debug this? Thanks.

Edited per comments.

config.rb

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.signup "/signup", :controller => "business_accounts", :action => "new"
  map.resources :beta_signups, :controller => 'public/beta_signups'
  map.root :controller => "public/pages", :action => "index"
end
```

For brevity, I commented out the rest of the routes and left in a couple of routes that work. The one that failed is the signup route, it simply hangs and never times out.

Here's are the relevant output from the development.log showing a route that works (root) and one that doesn't (signup)

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"public/pages"}
Rendering template within layouts/public
Rendering public/pages/index
Completed in 672ms (View: 656, DB: 15) | 200 OK [http://localhost/]
  SQL (0.0ms)   SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
  SQL (0.0ms)   SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'

Processing BusinessAccountsController#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-22 10:01:30)
 [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"business_accounts"}
```

Not sure if this makes any difference but it is running on thin and bundler.

Stripped the controller down to the bare minimum and still getting the same error

```
class BusinessAccountsController < SSLController
 def new
   logger.debug "here"
 end
end
```

And I just noticed SSLController, hmm, I need to look into that.

Comment: Edit your question to show us what's in `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: What is the last requests response code from the development log, for the route i mean?

Comment: So, can you show us what's in the BusinessAccountsController new action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son of a !@%$#@%$%!$@!%, SSLController was my problem, there is no SSL setup on my laptop and the net effect is the app hanging with no error message. Changing it to ApplicationController works. Thanks @Taryn, it was your request that made me looked closer at the code, funny how I've looked at it for days and never saw it till now.